# Is there a significant performance difference between Pseudo-Distributed and Fully-distributed mode in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I was reading the document of Hadoop, and I found this:

> "Both standalone mode and pseudo-distributed mode are provided for the purposes of small-scale testing".

I have 2 questions.

First, how big is considered as small-scale, more specifically, I'm going to use at most 32 nodes, is this ok for me to run it in the pseudo-distributed mode?

Second, even for small-scale, is there any performance difference between Pseudo-Distributed and Fully-distributed mode? Since, I'm running hadoop on my Mac, and it's kind difficult for me to find a really cluster system. Anything that I have to pay attention?

Answer (score 0):

> at most 32 nodes, is this ok for me to run it in the pseudo-distributed mode?

"Pseudo" distributed specifically means you **only have one node**. It means all Hadoop services are capable of talking to each other as if they were on an external interface (not all localhost) connection, and using HDFS, not just the local filesystem.

In order to create a "distributed mode"  cluster, you can add additional nodes to your single  node by using the correct configurations. Tip: Apache Ambari would make this process much easier.

However, HDFS will want to be able to replicate blocks at least three times by default, and in order to accommodate for downtime in these services, 5 nodes is a good minimum. I also recommend that you setup High Availability in your cluster using a standalone installation of 3 or 5 Zookeeper servers (must be odd, but no larger than 7)

Comment: In pseudo distributed mode, all services share one disk, will this become a short back when executing MapReduce job?

Comment: Yes, it will be a bottleneck. But you can have more than one disk on one machine